# Median method returning higher value median

Tags: java, arrays

So im writing a method in which it finds the median of an n-numbered array. If the array has an odd number of elements it works fine, however if the array has an even number of elements, I want the program to output the higher of the 2 middle numbers rather than the lower of the 2. At the current moment, my code is outputting the lower number. This is the code:

```
public Long getMedian() {

    long median = 0;

    Arrays.sort(elements);

    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        median = elements[length/2];
    } if (length % 2 == 0) {
        median = ((elements[length/2]) + (elements[(length/2) - 1])) / 2;
        median++;
    }

    return median;
}
```

For example, if the array with numbers `[30 41 45 50]` was inputted, the median would be 45, not 41. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly it is most straightforward solution:

```
public Long getMedian() {
    Arrays.sort(elements);

    return elements[elements.length / 2];
}
```

Comment: Wow that's incredible that such a simple approach could be overlooked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in your code, I suspect that the variable `length` is not `elements.length`.

Anyway, I use this median function:

```
public static double median(int[] values) {
    Arrays.sort(values);

    if (values.length == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (values.length % 2 == 0)
        return ((double)values[values.length/2] + (double)values[values.length/2 - 1])/2;
    else
        return (double)values[values.length/2];
}
```

Comment: the second if should return the max, not the average

Comment: @assylias why? if array has even number of elements, median is average of two centrals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Easy_explanation_of_the_sample_median

Comment: I agree but that's not what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double findmedian(int[] arr) {
    int middlevalue = arr.length/2;
    if (arr.length%2 == 1) {
        return arr[middle];
    } else {
        return (arr[middle-1] + arr[middle]) / 2.0;
    }
}
```

i think its best to return a double value when finding meadian. may be this approach will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the right border of your median like this:

```
median = elements[(length/2)]
```

for the even-case

Comment: For `[30 41 45 50]` it will give 50, as 4/2+1 = 3 (arrays in java are zero based)